# How to Convert from Date Object into a Range to Display at Bookmark in Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Context:  I am trying to create a document to where the document prompts the user for information.  Right now, I just trying to understand the reason I cannot get the date turned into a range to be able to display at the bookmark.

I have tried creating different types of objects to associate with Date but I just do not understand the reason I am getting a compile error.

```
Sub TodayDate()

Dim dateVariable 
dateVariable = Date

Set dateVariable = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmkTodayDate").Range
dateVariable.Text = dateVariable.value
```

I am wanting to display the date at the posted bookmark location ("bmkTodayDate"), but I keep getting error messages.  What is the correct object or the correct code that I should have used?

Comment: change your last line to `dateVariable = dateVariable.Text`

Comment: When having problems with code, it's important to mention the **error messages** and **which line** triggers what message. It's also important to think about what a variable (`dateVariable`) should contain. That means to explicilty `Dim As`, not leaving it up to chance. The sample code first assigns a `Date` to the variable, then it tries to set it to a `Range` object. It's not possible for both to be the case. For the code in the question **two** variables are needed: one for the date, the other for the `Range`. *Then* you can assign the one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some searching on the net, and I came up with a solution.  Cindy Meister was right that I need to declare some objects into existence.  I didn't realized that the bookmark object "bmkDate" needed to come into existence as well.

```
Sub TodayDate()
Dim bmkDate As Bookmark

Set bmkDate = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Date")
bmkDate.Range.Text = Date
```

Things to note: First, thank you Miles Flatt for your input. What I found that works for me is that "Date" is an actual posted/inserted bookmark within the Word document; the today variable Date is in the default format, so it will display mm/dd/yyyy at the location; and finally, the modifier/suffixes .Range.Text is what really helped. The Range.Text returns or sets the text in the specified range or selection.